# State is undefined in scope of map

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and trying to learn the concepts. I am creating demo sticky notes app on reactjs. I am getting error

> index.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notes' of undefined

I have Board component and Notes components as follows.

Notes Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Note extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {editing: false}
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
  }

  edit() {
    this.setState({editing: true});
  }

  save() {
    this.props.onChange(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).value, this.props.index);
    this.setState({editing: false});
  }

  remove() {
    this.props.onRemove(this.props.index);
  }

  renderDisplay() {
    return (
      <div className='note'>
      <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      <span>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'/>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash'/>
       </span>
     </div>
    );
   }

  renderForm() {
    return (
      <div className='note'>
         <textarea className='form-control' defaultValue={this.props.children} ref='newText'></textarea>
          <button className='btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk' onClick={this.save} />
      </div>
     );
    }

  render() {
    if(this.state.editing) {
      return this.renderForm();
    } else {
      return this.renderDisplay();
    }
  }
}

export default Note;
```

And Board Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Note from './Note';

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notes: [
        'Check emails',
        'Log in to jira',
        'Fix the issues',
        'Logout the system'
      ]
    }
  }

  update(newText, i) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state);
    var arr = this.state.notes;
    arr[i] = newText;
    this.setState({notes: arr});
  }

  remove(i) {
    var arr = this.state.notes;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({notes: arr});
  }

  eachNote(note, i) {
    return (
      <Note key={i}
            index={i}
            onChange={this.update}
            onRemove={this.remove}
      >{note}</Note>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='board'>
        {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote, this)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Board></Board>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
export default Board;
```

I am getting error when i try to update a note, as the note is render using the state notes variable and i have attached a property on each note as onChange: {this.update}. In update i am accessing state variable notes but state is undefined.

Can anyone give me suggestions about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
onChange={this.update.bind(this)}
```

Instead of:

```
onChange={this.update}
```

Comment: i am trying same for remove function, but its shows
index.js:28384 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null

Can you please suggest anything?

Comment: In `Note`s constructor you'r `bind`ing edit & save, try adding remove too..

Comment: Sorry i got it, i didnt bind the remove function to this in Note component. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, React recommends binding  event handlers in the constructor so they are only bound once for every instance.
Read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding